# what software was used to create qfield android app?

Tags: qfield

i imported the github android project from this link:https://github.com/opengisch/QField

however it showed android framework detected.it was obvious that the app was not created in android studio.
so what software was used ?how can i make changes to the app?

Comment: QGIS framework is QT5 so most likley this is the QT for Android http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html